# SQL - How to identify table rows that don't match what's normally in that column of the table

Tags: sql, subquery, having-clause

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to devise a query that will locate a row in a table that doesn't contain values that usually show up for that column.

For example, let's say I have the following table:

[image]

Let's say I have 2000 unique Box Numbers, that have handful of numbered balls in them with what color they are. For the most part, **all boxes should only have one color type in them** (let's say there are a total of 256 colors), but there are some that have more than one color in them.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to develop a query that will find which boxes have more than one color inside it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgres...?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution or just want to resolve exactly this case with different colours? They are very different tasks, and your question header is about more general one.

Comment: @astentx yeah, a general solution is what I'm looking for.  I have a similar situation

Comment: @Tscott General solution has a lot of complexity, because our world is not very simple and not all things can be counted easily. I mean you cannot call some value as extraordinary until you do not know the distribution of values. And when you've found some value to be less frequent than others, it may be ok because its distribution expects this rate. For example, observing 31 as the least common value of birth day of month is caused by the fact that 31 is less frequent by its nature, than 1.

Answer (score 0):

> develop a query that will find which boxes have more than one color inside it

If you want entire rows, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.box_number = t.box_number and t1.color <> t.color
)
```

If you just want the box numbers, then I would prefer `group by` and `having`:

```
select box_number
from mytable t
group by box_number
having min(color) <> max(color)
```

Comment: For your first query, `COUNT(DISTINCT color) OVER (PARTITION BY box_number)` is usually more performant. Yes, i know SQL Server can't do that, it would have to be in a subquery